# seleccion de varios checkbox en php

Tags: php

Buenos días comunidad.

Tengo la necesidad de controlar varios checkbox dinámicos que un usuario puede escoger. Por ello, en cada consulta, genero un checkbox-name para identificar a qué articulo corresponde.

En la parte del servidor, básicamente leo el array de las selecciones.

Lo que ocurre es que en la parte cliente creo que lo hago bien:

```
<table>
<form action="t2.php" method="POST">
   <?php while ($rowLin = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtLin, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
       <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="articulo-<?= $rowLin["CodigoArticulo"]; ?>"></td>
      <td><?php echo $rowLin["CodigoArticulo"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rowLin["DescripcionArticulo"]; ?></td>
          
              <? // Concatebi  el id del articulo al nombre del check para poder identificarlo  ?>
              <input type="hidden" value="<?= $rowLin["CodigoArticulo"]; ?>" name="articulos[]">
       </tr>
   <?php } ?>    
   <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
</table>
```

sin embargo, en la parte del servidor, los checkbox escogido me muestra el mensaje correcto pero aquellos que no fueron escogidos, me muestra el mensaje:
Notice: Undefined index: articulo-AABBCC in C:\xampp\htdocs\0_codis_proves\t2.php on line 13

el código en servidor es el siguiente

```
if($_POST){
    // Se obtiene el array(lista) de alumnos
    $articulos = (array)$_POST["articulos"];

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach( $articulos as $articulo){
       echo "<li>";
       echo 'articulo: ' . $articulo;
       // para hacer referencia al check correcto
       $valor = $_POST["articulo-" . $articulo] == 'on' ? "Si" : "No";
       echo " Seleccionado:" . $valor;
       echo "</li>"; 
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Os agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda ya que llevo bastante dándole vueltas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es algo muy comun al trabajar con checkboxes. Lo que pasa es que los checkboxes no chequeados pasan a ser controles inactivos, y por lo tanto, no se envian con el resto de los datos del formulario (Ver https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls).

Por ejemplo:

Solo obtendras `articulo-1` en PHP.

**Opcion 1**

Lo que puedes hacer es, primero, interpretar los items que no tengan valor como no chequeados, cambiando el código aquí (evitando un warning por no existir la clave):

```
$valor = if (isset($_POST["articulo-" . $articulo]) && $_POST["articulo-" . $articulo] == 'on') ? "Si" : "No";
```

Y asegurarte de enviar un valor 'on' (`value='on'`)cuando este chequeado:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="articulo-<?= $rowLin["CodigoArticulo"]; ?>" value='on'>
```

**Opcion 2**

Y la otra opcion es solo del lado del cliente, generar un codigo adicional (input *hidden* con el mismo nombre) para que el checkbox *siempre* envie un valor, incluso en el caso de que no este chequeado (enviando un string vacio), en caso de estar marcado enviara el valor `'on'`:

```
<td>
  <input type="hidden" name="articulo-<?= $rowLin["CodigoArticulo"]; ?>" value=''>
  <input type="checkbox" name="articulo-<?= $rowLin["CodigoArticulo"]; ?>" value='on'>
</td>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @F.Igor por tu ayuda. Me ha ido genial y de paso he aprendido algo nuevo.